# How to distribute values in Python?

Tags: python, data-science

so I am trying to calculate the likeliness of floats on CSGO skins.
A float is a value between **0 and 1** and they are distinguished in **five sections**.

Factory New *(0 to 0.07) 3%*, Minimal Wear *(0.07 to 0.14) 24%*, Field-Tested *(0.14 to 0.38) 33%*, Well-Worn *(0.38 to 0.45) 24%* and Battle-Scarred *(0.45 to 1.0) 16%*.

As you can see the distribution among the float values is not even, but **weighed**. However in each section the values are then **spread evenly**, for example:
https://blog.csgofloat.com/content/images/2020/07/image-6.png

It then gets tricky when you introduce **float caps**, meaning the float is no longer between 0 and 1, but fo example between 0.14 and 0.65.

The value is calculated how follows:

1. A section is selected **according to their weights**.
2. A float in the range of that section is **randomly generated**.
3. The final float is calculated according to this formula:
   **final_float = float * (max_float - min_float) + min_float**
   float being the randomly generated value, max and min_float the upper and lower cap (in this case 0.14 and 0.65).

I now want to calculate the **distribution** of skins with a cap **among the five sections**.

How would I do this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple using `numpy` library:

```
import numpy as np

# input data
n_types = 5
types_weights = np.array([0.03, 0.24, 0.33, 0.24, 0.16])
types_intervals = np.array([0.0, 0.07, 0.14, 0.38, 0.45, 1.0])

# simulate distribution, by generating `n_samples` random floats 
n_samples = 1000000
type_samples = np.random.choice(range(n_types), p=types_weights, size=n_samples, replace=True, )
float_ranges_begin = types_intervals[type_samples]
float_ranges_end = types_intervals[type_samples + 1]
float_samples = float_ranges_begin + np.random.rand(n_samples) * (float_ranges_end - float_ranges_begin)

# plot results
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.hist(float_samples, bins=100, density=True, rwidth=0.8)
# to see types names instead
# plt.xticks(types_intervals, types + ['1.0'], rotation='vertical', fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel('Float', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Probability density', fontsize=16);
```

[image]

**EDIT**

If you wanted to find the *exact* distribution, then it's easy aswell, though your "scalable" requirement is not fully clear to me

```
n_types = 5
types = ['Factory New', 'Minimal Wear', 'Field-Tested', 'Well-Worn', 'Battle-Scarred']
types_weights = np.array([0.03, 0.24, 0.33, 0.24, 0.16])
types_intervals = np.array([-0.0001, 0.07, 0.14, 0.38, 0.45, 1.0])

# corerspond to top values on my plot, approximately [0.4 3.4 1.37 3.4 0.3]
types_probability_density = types_weights / (types_intervals[1:] - types_intervals[:-1])

def float_probability_density(x):
  types = np.searchsorted(types_intervals, x) - 1
  return types_probability_density[types]

sample_floats = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 100)
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.bar(sample_floats, float_probability_density(sample_floats), width=0.005)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I thought of doing it the same way, however ths will scale poorly, won't it? Is there a way to only calculate the borders between each section and from there deduct the distribution?

Comment: @ChristianKammerer what is your goal? Why would you need to scale it? It takes a fraction of a second to compute for 1 million samples.

Comment: Thank you so much. With scaling I meant more different items, not samples. So like 300 different items. But if it only takes a fraction of a second as you said, that will be okay. I have not implemented your solution yet, as I was stuck in a lecture. Have a good day. :)

Comment: @ChristianKammerer I've edited the answer for the exact plot of distribution, check it out